# Change icon for a Delphi console application

Tags: delphi, console-application

How do I change the program icon for a Delphi console application?

The application settings is greyed in a console application.

Bye.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [a July 2007 blog article by Nibu Thomas](http://ntcoder.com/bab/2007/07/24/changing-console-application-window-icon-at-runtime/), there seems to be a `SetConsoleIcon` WinAPI function.

Alternatively just put the icon in a resource file. Windows should use the first icon it encounters in the application's resources as the application icon.

Answer (score 13):

If the option to change the icon is disabled, then it is because you have deleted or neglected to add the following line from your DPR file:

```
{$R *.res}
```

Put it back, or add it if you never had it. The icon setting will be re-enabled, as will the version-information settings. If the resource file does not exist, then the IDE will create it for you. Do not edit that resource file (such as to add your own icons or other resources); it is for the IDE's use only.

Comment: adding {$R *.res} does not work here - tested in Delphi 7 and 2009. In Delphi 2009 however the icon can be added using Project | Resources, the project file will then have a line {$R *.dres}

Comment: Dres? Man, I'm out of touch. But it doesn't work in Delphi 7, either? That surprises me. :/ You're sure you put it in the right place in the file?

Comment: Worked for me, added the code in my dpr and set the icon as i normally do in a form application

Answer (score 10):

if you add

```
application.Run;
```

somewhere in your dpr file you can use the project->options to change the icon. 
After you have changed the icon just remove  "application.Run;" again and you can compile/build with new icon.

Comment: doesnt work buddy , as console apps do not have Application object

Comment: This works for me in Delphi/BDS 2007, just add application.run in the dpr if it is missing (even if it breaks the build), change your icon/settings then comment it out until you need to make any changes again. best adding a comment as to why its there in the first place.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me in Delphi 7(Don't ask why we're still using Delphi 7, but it is lean, mean and clean for a console app)

Comment: #CyprUS, you're right there is no Application objection in a console app, but it's not for building the app! It's just to fool the IDE into enabling Project > Options > Application  > Application Settings. In fact in my code, it isn't even inside the begin...end block, and it still fools the IDE to enabling that option. Once you've added the icon, and the IDE has saved it into your AppName.res file, you comment out that line, keep calm, and build away :)

Answer (score 8):

Simply change the Icon in your apps resource file (say your app project is called ConsoleApp.dpr, your app resource file will be ConsoleApp.res)

The main icon resource in there is intuatively called MAINICON, just replace it.

Here is a [step by step](http://www.decompile.com/cpp/faq/console_icon.htm) for C++ Builder (the steps are basically the same in Delphi)

Answer (score 3):

1. add {$R *.res} in your DPR file
2. comment {$APPTYPE CONSOLE} line in your DPR file
3. edit Project -> Options -> Application -> Icon
4. uncomment {$APPTYPE CONSOLE} line in your DPR file

*Tested with Delphi XE*