# Changing project icon

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

So I started a project by adding my code to an existing project. The previous project used a res file to hold its icon, and loaded the res in the dpr.

Anyway, if I go to the Project->Options->Application... I should be able to decide what icon I want to use for my project ( using Load icon... button)
But my icon and Load icon button are disabled, and I have no idea on how to re-enable them.
I really dont want to start a new project from scratch now, and move the whole code there. It would be a huge waste of time.

I never had this problem before...
Anybody has any idea why this happens?
Again, how do I change my application's icon?

Comment: Do you have a `{$R *.RES}` line in your .DPR file?

Comment: What type of application (FMX or VCL)? GUI (forms) or console?

Comment: Check the answers to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627526/change-icon-for-a-delphi-console-application). Maybe one of them applies to your case.

Comment: Since it works for the rest of us, the answer must lie in the specifics of what you have done. Until the problem can be reproduced there is no question here.

Comment: So the app is VCL with GUI. And my DPR file had a `{$R *.RES}` but it was different... it was: `{$R *.dres}` have no idea why... Thank you --500-Internal Server Error-- for pointing me into the right direction.

Comment: Make your comment into an Answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able  swap the icon image just use the same name and delete the old image.